# How to remove a class from an element when click anywhere on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide an element when click anywhere on the page but the div, and if you do click while over the div, then it should toggle the class.

jQuery -

```
 $('.onclick-dropdown-link').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);
     var id = $this.attr('href');
     $('.onclick-dropdown').not(id).removeClass('open');
     $(id).toggleClass('open');
 });
```

HTML -

```
<a class="onclick-dropdown-link" href="#test-div"></a>
<div id="test-div" class="onclick-dropdown">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.onclick-dropdown {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}
.onclick-dropdown.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Already tried with below methods -

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.onclick-dropdown').not(id).removeClass('open');
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.open').not(id).removeClass('open');
});

$('.onclick-dropdown-link').on('click', function() {
       e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
return false;  ;
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.onclick-dropdown.open').removeClass('.open');
});
```

Comment: You may find it easier to put this into a jsfiddle. It will be faster for you to debug what you've done so far and for people to provide edits to that to fix things for you.

Comment: Why not hide all dropdowns and after show the addressed one?

Comment: does your code do anything that you want it to?  what specifically is it not doing that it should, or doing that it shouldn't?

Comment: I do notice that the last portion of your provided javascript `$('.onclick-dropdown.open').removeClass('.open');` will not remove the open class because of the prepended `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/t3y5zo2t/

```js
$('.onclick-dropdown-link').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   var $this = $(this);
   var id = $this.attr('href');
   $('.onclick-dropdown').not(id).removeClass('open');
   $(id).toggleClass('open');
});

$('body:not(.onclick-dropdown-link)').click(function(e){
  $('#test-div').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.onclick-dropdown {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}
.onclick-dropdown.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a class="onclick-dropdown-link" href="#test-div">test</a>
<div id="test-div" class="onclick-dropdown">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this row:

```
$('.onclick-dropdown-link').on('click', function() {
  e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
  return false;
});
```

you forgot to pass `$event` to your function. It should looks like this:

```
$('.onclick-dropdown-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
  return false;
});
```

and this code should work.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfgr9/540/

Comment: @rowdy, check out the jsFiddle in my answer, it works